# Useful bijections

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

Could someone please provide me with some useful bijections one ought to know for an upcoming examination on cardinality with an emphasis on proofs?

For example, the bijective mapping $f : (-1, 1) \mapsto \mathbb{R}: f(x) = tan(\frac{\pi x}{2})$ can be used to prove that the set of real numbers has the cardinality, $c$ of the continuum etc. And Cantor's diagonalization argument can be used to show that the closed interval $[0, 1]$ is uncountable. Any similar functions that are extremely useful in this regard.

Comment: This question is horribly broad...

Comment: Honestly the best you can do in this matter is remembering your elementary functions and their properties, and being able to think on your feet. You might have to get creative, depending on how nasty the prof wants to be on the matter, either by composing or augmenting the definitions somehow.

Comment: To exemplify what Eevee Trainer says, your $\tan(\pi x/2)$ is actually $x\mapsto \tan x$, which is a function you ought to be familiar with anyways, together with $x\mapsto \frac{\pi x}{2}$ whose only purpose is to get the domain just right.

Comment: I'd use $f(x)=\frac1{1-x}-\frac 1{1+x}$ instead of any trigonometry-related stuff. (This is also, along Eevee Trainer's comment, quickly pieced together according to needs

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes maps that make single points "disappear" are useful to have available up your sleeves, e.g.
$$\begin{align} f\colon \Bbb R &\to \Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\\x&\mapsto \begin{cases}x+1&x\in\Bbb N_0\\x&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\end{align}$$
or
$$\begin{align} f\colon [0,1] &\to [0,1)\\x&\mapsto \begin{cases}\frac1{\frac 1x+1}=\frac x{x+1}&\frac1x\in\Bbb N\\x&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\end{align}$$
This can readily be adjusted to make finitely or countably infinitely many points "disappear".